# SwiftUI - scanning QR codes in the macOS app

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, avfoundation, qr-code

I am working on a Mac application that will read the QR code from the camera and then read the text from it.

Unfortunately, CodeScanner package is only for iOS and there is no method called:

```swift
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

Of course, to use it, the *AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate* has to be included - Unfortunately, this protocol is not available on macOS.

**Is there any way to create a macOS QR code scanner using SwiftUI?**

I currently have a MacBook camera preview built-in, but I miss the thing to catch QR codes is missing:

```swift
final class PlayerContainerView: NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewType = PlayerView
    
    let captureSession: AVCaptureSession
    
    init(captureSession: AVCaptureSession) {
        self.captureSession = captureSession
    }
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> PlayerView {
        return PlayerView(captureSession: captureSession)
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: PlayerView, context: Context) {}
}

class PlayerView: NSView {
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    
    init(captureSession: AVCaptureSession) {
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        setupLayer()
    }
    
    func setupLayer() {
        previewLayer?.frame = self.frame
        previewLayer?.contentsGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        previewLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        previewLayer?.connection?.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
        
        if let mirroringSupported = previewLayer?.connection?.isVideoMirroringSupported {
            if mirroringSupported {
                previewLayer?.connection?.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
                previewLayer?.connection?.isVideoMirrored = true
            }
        }

        
        layer = previewLayer
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any delegation protocol which would work like AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate and allowed me to catch the metadata objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too was was surprised that macOS `AVFoundation` didn't support  `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`, but `CoreImage` supports QR codes, and this worked for me:

```
let qrDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeQRCode, context: nil, options: nil)!

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
    
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: imageBuffer)
    let features = qrDetector.features(in: ciImage)

    for feature in features {
        let qrCodeFeature = feature as! CIQRCodeFeature
        print("messageString \(qrCodeFeature.messageString!)")
    }
}
```

There's probably a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! 

I was searching for an alternative to VNDetectBarcodesRequest (because it somehow leaks memory?!) and the one you proposed uses way less memory (roughly one third of the one used with the Vision framework). 

To make it a bit more efficient I just set an iterator to skip some frames, so the analysis is only done every X frames.